# Copy if statement

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I would like to copy the values from the "BALANCE" column from the nostra tab if it meets the BANK condition in the NAME column. Is this code going in the right direction?

```
With wbMe.Sheets("nostra")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range("A1:I11")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Bank "
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wbMe.Sheets("papiery").Range("A5")
End With
```

Comment: `.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlVisible)` this will be A to G filtered, also, you dont paste.  I think copying `.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlVisible).column(` and then pasting that, i've not tested yet, i'll try in a sec.

Comment: The direction is right, but there are some issues. Is this a range or an Excel table? Do you want the code to find the columns or are they fixed (e.g. the `NAME` column is 1, the `BALANCE` column is unknown: need to find it)? Do you want to copy the header, too? You have a trailing space in `"Bank "`. Is that correct, a typo or do you need to filter on the values that begin with `Bank`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 I would like the code after finding "Bank" to copy the value from the "Balance" column to destination, not all the rows from the headers. Space is wrong its only typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy An Auto-Filtered Column

**A Quick Fix**

```
With wbMe.Sheets("nostra")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range("A1:I11")
        Dim cIndex As Variant
        cIndex = Application.Match("BALANCE", .Rows(1), 0)
        If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Bank"
            Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), .Columns(cIndex)) _
                .Copy Destination:=wbMe.Sheets("papiery").Range("A5")
        End If
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: It works very well, tell me if there is a chance that as there will be more records that meet the criteria, it will add up the values from the balance column?

Comment: Don't understand your question. Do you mean that you want to return the sum of the values of the Balance column?

Comment: Excatly. Return sum of the values of the balance column

Comment: e.g. `Debug.Print Application.Sum(Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), .Columns(cIndex)))`. But you better use variables: `Dim vrg as range: Set vrg  = Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), .Columns(cIndex))` : `Dim Total As Double: Total = Application.Sum(vrg)` : `Debug.Print Total`.

Comment: Ok but how to add to your code :    ` Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), .Columns(cIndex)) _
                .Copy Destination:=wbMe.Sheets("papiery").Range("Q42") ? `

Comment: i mean how to past result sum in destination?

Comment: `wbMe.Sheets("papiery").Range("Q42").Value = Total`. Or `wbMe.Sheets("papiery").Range("Q42").Value = Application.Sum(Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), .Columns(cIndex)))`